# C++ initializer list heap allocation

Tags: c++, allocation

I am making a simple hashset, and I decided to do a separated chaining to prevent collisions, so I made a class, and made a constructor like this:

Here are the fields of class:

```
std::list<V>* vals;
const int _buckets = 3001;
```

```
HashSet() : vals(new std::list<V>[_buckets])
{}
```

And also tried this:

```
HashSet() : _buckets(3001), vals(new std::list<V>[_buckets])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < _buckets; i++)
      std::cout << i << ' ' << vals[i].size() << '\n'; // Crashes here at i = 234
}
```

And it throwed an exception plus when I tried to get size of each list it was garbage

But, when I did allocation in constructor body, everything was as expected

```
HashSet()
{ vals = new std::list<V>[_buckets]; }
```

My question is, what's the deal with allocation in initializer list and how to fix what I did

Comment: Please post a [mre], with complete error messages.

Comment: In your `HashSet` class, is `_buckets` declared before `vals`? If it is another way around then you have an uninitialized member variable before attempting to use it in an expression.

Comment: Please post real code. The missing information here is how you are declaring, initialising and using `_buckets`

Comment: I'd second the call for a [mcve]. Furthermore, consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com (read their site guidelines first!), because I can already sense a few bad ideas. For example, allocating an array of something instead of using `std::vector` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Members are always initialized from top to bottom in declaration order. The initialzier list **doesn't** decide the order (but the compiler should give you a warning when the order is different).

Comment: @heapunderrun Thanks for the advice, I think I got it, I think it's because compiler decides to allocate array before initializing _buckets, so that be it, thanks again

Comment: First question to think: Do linklist provide you provide you O(1) read operation?
Probably you want something like this `std::array<std::list<v>, _buckets?`

Comment: _"compiler decides to allocate array before initializing _buckets"_ - as written above, this is because `_buckets` is declared _after_ `vals`.